# Evaluate $a^i$ where $a$ is real:

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a question involving the evaluation of $3^i$, but I am unsure how to do this. I know how to solve such questions involving $e^{i\theta}$, but how does this work with a different base? (I understand that the angle is 1 radian).

I have attempted to convert $3$ to Euler's form giving $3 \ e^{0}$ but this does not get me anywhere. What is the general way to solve questions in the form $a^i, a\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641312/all-possible-values-of-i-2i-nbhm-2013#comment1352043_641312

Comment: See the first answer in the question Poppy linked to.  Even though the title of the question is $i^{-2i}$, the answer is general

Comment: $3^i=e^{i\cdot\ln3}$.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz That did it for me, thanks.

Comment: Regardless, you might wish to read the answer in that thread. In particular, there's an important difference between $e^i$ and $3^i$, pertaining to the properties of the complex $\ln$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/complexexp.html:

> Finally, for a real number $a$, you can define $a^{(b+ic)}$ by writing $a = e^{\ln a}$:
>   \begin{align}
> a^{b+ic} &= e^{(\ln a)(b+ic)} = e^{(b\ln a) + i(c\ln a)}\\
> &= e^{(b\ln a)}\left(\cos(c\ln a)+i\sin(c\ln a)\right)\\
> &= a^b\left(\cos(c\ln a)+i\sin(c\ln a)\right)
> \end{align}

That simplifies to this form:

$$
\cos (\ln(a))+i \sin (\ln(a))
$$

Hence,

$$
3^i=\cos (\ln (3))+i \sin (\ln (3))
$$

Also, interesting side-note: any problem of form $a^i, a\in \mathbb{R}$ can be expressed in polar coordinates as $r=1, \theta=\frac{180 \ln (a)}{\pi }{}^{\circ}$

Comment: Should it not be $3^i=\cos{\ln{3}} + i\sin{\ln{3}}$ then? That's is what the other answers brought to my understanding.

Comment: Yes, Ruben. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm used to just writing $\log$ because in my math class, $\log$ is implied to be $\ln$.

Comment: I'm in CS, where there are many $\log$s. But a math prof of mine once said that "there's only one $\log$." :-)

Comment: @JohnMoeller here, in fact, that are *many* different $\log$'s ;) (Although the interesting distinction is their domain and range rather than base.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $ e^{i\theta}=(e^{\theta})^i.$  To find $3^i $, first solve $e^{\theta}=3$.